# Is it possible to specify a default ros version with the roswiki macros?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm writing ros-distribution-specific wiki pages as shown in the bottom of the post, and I'd like to display by default a page that does not correspond to the latest stable release (in my case i want to display diamondback instead of electric). Is this possible?, and if so, where can I find the relevant documentation?.

TIA.

```
<<Version()>>

{{{#!wiki version diamondback
<<Include(foo/diamondback)>>
}}}

{{{#!wiki version electric
<<Include(foo/electric)>>
}}}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11726/is-it-possible-to-specify-a-default-ros-version-with-the-roswiki-macros?/) by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3907 on 2011-10-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The default version is currently hardcoded in the javascript.  We don't have cycles to rewrite this right now, but would happily accept a patch to the javascript and wiki macro code that would enable more customized setting.

The code for the javascript is here:

http://ros.org/_wiki/common/js/rosversion.js

The code for the version macro is here:

https://code.ros.org/svn/ros/stacks/rosorg/trunk/roswiki/macro/

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-10-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The version is global (recently changed to Electric).

I don't know any way to override that. Maybe someone else does.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-10-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) on 2011-11-01**:
The clear heading stating the supported version is what I had and I'll stick to that for now. Thanks all for pointing out the relevant places that enforce the current behavior.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-10-28**:
You can write you're own buttons using the seesaw macros http://www.ros.org/wiki/seesawexample but I'd recommend not doing that and just putting a clear header at the top, saying "If you want Diamondback, click below."  Or you could lay the documentation out side by side and not use any macros.